# VB.NET not showing picture?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm not sure what's going on but the picture is not showing , only thing I get is only a blank with borders.

I get the avatar depends on the username on the database :

```
Private Function grab_p_pic(ByVal username As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Using saConn As New SqlConnection(fyben_reader)
            Dim query As String = "SELECT profile_pic_url FROM fybens_lair_website.dbo.db_web_profile WHERE username = '" & SafeSqlLiteral(username) & "'"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, saConn)

            saConn.Open()

            Using saReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While saReader.Read
                    profile_pic_url.ImageUrl = saReader("profile_pic_url")
                End While
            End Using
            saConn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        submitError(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Design :

```
<div class='right_content' style='text-align: center;'>
                            <div id="profile_pic" runat="server">
                                <asp:Image ID="profile_pic_url" runat="server" Height="120" Width="120" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What is the HTML that is output on your page? Is there a value in the src attribute of your img tag?

Comment: I can't seem to understand your question honestly , mind rephrasing ? I don't have a good english

Comment: Look at the resulting HTML in the page source in your browser.  What is created by this `asp:Image` control?

Comment: <div class='right_content' style='text-align: center;'>
                                <div id="profile_pic">
                                   <img id="profile_pic_url" src="" style="height:120px;width:120px;" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
It seems like the src have nothing , why is that